Change Facebook "Most Relevant" comment default ranking to "All Comments" with javascript?
Would like to have Facebook display "All Comments" when I click comments on a post, instead of default "Most Relevant". I expect someone has already done this with JavaScript? Hoping to get something going without digging into Facebook code to work this out. Any help appreciated.
Have tried several different how-tos from online sources of how to turn of comment ranking in Facebook using their settings, but none will turn on default display of all comments. I also searched for Facebook add-ons or extensions to do this, but found none.I programmed web pages at UNM 10 years ago, but have forgotten a lot more than I remember. Even pointers on where to start, rough outlines or anything would be helpful. I know this can be done and likely already had been done with JavaScript, if not some simpler way.
